# 1970s book about a boy on an island which is split in two by a wall with lizard-like monsters on one side of it

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book at school in the late 1970s/early 1980s about a boy on an island which is split in two by a wall with lizard-like monsters on the other side of it. They haven’t attacked in a long time but are about to now.

I loved it and it started my love of sci fi/fantasy, but I can’t remember the name of it!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall anything about the cover of this book?